# How to optimise storing and fetching from a huge list in php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

Thanks in advance for helping,

I have a list of one million names and nicknames,
each name has only one nickname. each name has it's corresponding nickname (even if it's the same)

I normally use PHP and MySQL to store data in rows and then use a select statement to fetch. I consult you because of the volume this method might not be optimised.

A script will be created that needs to get each time the corresponding nicknames of about 600 names out of the million, this will be executed with each user pageload.

I have experience in working with PHP and MySQL

I can construct the data in whatever way is best, plain text, mysql or something else.

Whats the best way to store and fetch this data set ?

Comment: Store in MySQL with an index on the `name` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. #### Pagination / Lazy-loading

   Never load all items at once. Have them load incrementally. A real life example would be Facebook and Twitter. It only loads a set amount of items, then when you reach the bottom or click on "load more", it loads the next N items or Google, which only shows N items per page out of a billion possible results.
2. #### Use JSON

   These days, I still see people return formatted HTML in AJAX requests - don't do that. Have your server load the initial page (which has initial HTML), and the rest in JSON via AJAX. Have some client-side templating script create the HTML for you when the JSON data arrives. This saves you bandwidth and download time.
3. #### Use Compression

   It's pretty obvious why you should use compression.
4. #### Load only the required fields in SQL

   Often times, you load all columns because "they might be useful someday" - no. If you want to load a set of nicknames, have SQL load only the nicknames. Of course, the primary key field is always required for pairing, so in this case, 2 columns.

And seeing that it's only a 1-to-1 relationship between the nickname and the person, store it in the same table. There is little need for it to be in another table. This saves you from a JOIN operation.

Answer (score 0):

As eggyql mentioned add in index to your name column. Also set a limit to your sql select `SELECT name, nickname FROM your_table LIMIT 0, 10`