# What is the best way to send worth 10 mb of data to the client side grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a JqGrid and I need to send about 10Mb of data to it as json to populate the grid. I send the Json as a content result like this:

```
    public ContentResult GetDynamicColumnData(int? fieldListId)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

        IList<FieldListView> fieldListValues = null;
        if (fieldListId != null)
        {
            fieldListValues = fieldListService.GetFieldListValues(fieldListId.Value);
        }
        var resultData = new { fieldListValues };
        var result = new ContentResult
        {
            Content = serializer.Serialize(resultData),
            ContentType = "application/json"
        };
        return result;
    }
```

The List called fieldListvalues has around 50000 objects.
The problem is my Jqgrid takes some 3 minutes to load in Chrome and it doesn't load in firefox at all.

So what is the best way to send that huge data to the client side and render it in a grid.

Comment: seriously? 10MB? Then [a previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10371912/575527) of mine could help, but still, 10MB?

Comment: Replace jqGrid with [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) -> supports server side processing - so it only retrieves the data visible to the user ...

Comment: jqGrid supports server side pagination - http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx use this method

Comment: I would monitor this in chrome net / firebugs / fiddler but I am guessing the time taken is not the download time but the javascript DOM manipulation.  If this is the case then you have to think of an alternative approach to displaying the data (possibly pagination).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a pagination.

You can also use a incremental data load. So that you keep fetching more records but the user is able to see the screen and work with current set of data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement auto loading of data on scrolling/paging (which I believe JqGrid implements) so that the grid only requests data for the number of rows that are "viewable" by the user. It's just not going to work loading 10MB of data into the grid at once. I would question why that amount of data is actually needed by the user all at once. You could cut the amount of data down by pre-filtering etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to really don't do this.  That much data is going to make the grid itself hideous to use with so many rows.  You can configure the jqGrid to pagination.  You need to set the method signature in C# to something like

```
public ContentResult GetDynamicColumnData(int? fieldListId, 
                                 string sidx, string sord, 
                                 bool _search, string searchField, 
                                 string searchOper, string searchString, 
                                 int page = 1, int rows = 100)
```

Then you can iterate through your field list values skiping the total of pageIndex * pageSize and it should give a nice user experience.

When I did this I found this [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) article a good starting point.  I have also found this to be a [useful example](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/17/38229/).

You can use the _search and search operands to give a positive user experience by allowing the further filtering of the grid.  Because this search is dynamic I implemented it by building Predicates to then apply to a LINQ expression.